# Amazon aws-android-sdk problem on DroidX

Tags: android, exception, amazon-s3, certificate

I am using aws-android-sdk and on DroidX all was fine. But after last
system update DroidX cant get pictures from amazon. In logs i see

```
 01-29 04:18:36.332: WARN/HttpClient(2562): Unable to execute HTTP
 request: org.bouncycastle.jce.exception.ExtCertPathValidatorException:
 Could not validate certificate: current time: Sat Jan 29 04:18:36 GMT
 2000, validation time: Sun Oct 01 05:00:00 GMT 2006
```

What happens ? Is it possible avoid this ? I know that same problem on
Motorola Atrix.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon had a problem yesterday. You can look server status here: http://status.aws.amazon.com/

More info: [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=amazon%20aws&hl=en&nord=1&site=&prmd=ivnsl&source=lnt&tbs=qdr%3ah&sa=X&ei=zME_TrKVEYLoOZzTzPkO&ved=0CAwQpwUoAQ&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&ion=1&biw=1280&bih=686#hl=en&pwst=1&nord=1&tbs=qdr%3ad&sa=X&ei=TMI_TuWyE4ue-wbLur2HDw&sqi=2&ved=0CC4QvwUoAQ&q=amazon%20aws%20lightning&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.&fp=afdfed4f41684193&ion=1&biw=1280&bih=686)

But maybe that's not the problem. I don't know.